# Linear Programming: binary positive, negative and zero of a continuous variable

Tags: linear-programming

For my continuous variable `x` subject to constraint `-M <= x <= M`, I'm trying to derive the following:

- Binary positive (`p`) such that where `x > 0`, `p = 1` and where `x <= 0`, `p = 0`.
- Binary negative (`n`) such that where `x < 0`, `n = 1` and where `n >= 0`, `n = 0`.
- Binary zero (`z`) such that where `x == 0`, `z = 1` and where `x > 0` or `x < 0` , `z = 0`.

I've tried using the big M method, and I can force p and n to be 1 when `x >= 0` and `x <= 0` respectively, but I can't figure a way force them to be zero when x is.

Any help very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would think something like this would work...

```
x <= p * M

x >= n * (-M)

z <= 1 - p + n
```

This construct **assumes** there is some incentive in the objective function that credits `z` being zero.  Other constraints may be necessary if you need to enforce a different kind of inference, something else may be needed, depending on what the pressures are from the objective function.

Comment: It doesn't work as nothing stops p=1 if x<0

Answer (score -2):

Try the following
`p+n+z = 1`
`M(z+p-n-1) <= x <= M(1+p-z-n)`